# Oauth2 Authentication with outlook Calendar api using C# (or) Postman

Tags: c#, azure, postman, outlook-calendar

I need to access Outlook Calendar API for that needed Authentication so in Azure Active Directory I did App Registration and trying to get bearer token to access for that I used Client_id, Secret_Id, and tenant_id but am getting an error

Am getting Token but unable to access, Please check with below screenshots

[BEARER TOKEN](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gYlIm.png)

[ACCESS ISSUE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZZBYr.png)

Comment: MS recommends using the graph api instead of the older outlook api, unless there's some functionality that only exists in the outlook api. However, I tried to reproduce your error. I managed to get a 401 error when I used my hotmail account to login. Are you using a private email address or an organizational account? If organizational, does the account have a mailbox enabled? Also, check if there's a "X-Ms-Diagnostics" header in the response from outlook.office.com, it might contain some information on what's going wrong.

Comment: I created a Trail Office Account  for testing purpose, i am a beginner if you have a solution Share it Advance Appreciations.